# HTML5 Canvas: Как обновить холст?

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Как обновить холст canvas?

`clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);` - а как указать, какой холст нужно обновить?

Answer (score 1):

```
clearRect(0, 0, ширина_холста, высота_холста);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
переменная_холста.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// какой-то код ...

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector ("canvas").getContext ("2d") 
// холст
```